# Reduce an application's SQL Server buffer usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have a Visitor Tracking database which receives `INSERT` commands from several different applications on two servers.

It only receives `SELECT` queries when the admin backend requests a list of visits (not public facing).

Is there any reason that this database would require 80000 buffer pages and 687MB of SQL Server buffer memory, and can we do anything to reduce it?

Comment: Is 687MB an issue? Is the server running out of memory?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any reason that this database would require 80000 Buffer pages and 687MB of SQL Buffer

SQL brings required pages into buffer,when needed and keeps them as long there is no memory pressure

> and can we do anything to reduce it?

I don't see a reason why you need to reduce this and not be able to afford less than 1 GB of buffer is not good thing

There is  a command which can clean buffer pool,but i would strongly recommend against it

```
dbcc dropcleanbuffers
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I have no problem with 687MB if it needs it but this is one of 30 databases on the server and the only one that doesn't contain user-facing data. (It's used for page tracking.) The server has more than enough memory.

Comment: @MassiveGeek ,you don't need to unless ,you are facing memory issues

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase. I fear, as this is a one table database, that I am making an error in the programming that is causing this problem. If I had a memory leak in an application, regardless of whether the server had "enough memory," I would try to solve it because it's crazy not to. A one table DB surely shouldn't be using this much memory...